# Timer React + Redux. React don't dispatch action by timer (SetInterval) in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make a timer in my App with React + Redux.
So I have a component parent:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose } from "redux";

import QuestionCounter from "../question-counter";
import FinishButton from "../finish-button";
import TimeCounter from "../time-counter";
import PauseButton from "../pause-button";

import testFinished from "../../actions/test-finished";
import timerTick from "../../actions/timer-tick";
import setTimer from "../../actions/set-timer";

import totalWithEwStruct from "../hoc/total-with-ew-structure";
import withIndicators from "../hoc/with-indicators";

const Total = ({ total, testFinished }) => {
  const { finishedCount, totalCount, isPaussed, timeLeft } = total;
  return (
    <div className="test-total">
      <QuestionCounter
        finishedCount={finishedCount}
        totalCount={totalCount}
        testFinished={testFinished}
      />
      <FinishButton testFinished={testFinished} />
      <TimeCounter
        timeLeft={timeLeft}
        testFinished={testFinished}
        setTimer={setTimer}
        timerTick={timerTick}
      />
      <PauseButton isPaussed={isPaussed} />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ total, loading, error }) => {
  return { total, loading, error };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  testFinished,
  setTimer,
  timerTick
}

export default compose(
  totalWithEwStruct(),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withIndicators()
)(Total);
```

I try use timerTick by timer in componentDidMount

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TimeCounter extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { setTimer, timerTick } = this.props;
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      timerTick();
      console.log("tick");
    }, 1000);
    setTimer(timer);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { timeLeft, testFinished } = this.props;
    if (timeLeft <= 0) {
      testFinished();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { timeLeft } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="question-counter__timeleft">
        Времени осталось
        <span className="question-counter__timer">{timeLeft}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So I see "tick" - "tick" - "tick" in console, but React doesn't dispatch my `timerTick()` function to reducer.
I have tried log to console `action.type` for debugging, and there is no action of `timerTick`.

```
const timerTick = () => {
  return {
    type: "TIMER_TICK"
  };
};

export default timerTick;
```

Its code of action.

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: The actions are not getting dispatched since, in ````Total```` component, you are passing the imported method ````timerTick````. You are only creating the action and not dispatching it. Can you try passing the props ````timerTick```` instead of imported ````timerTick```` to ````TimeCounter```` in ````Total```` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Total component needs to take `timerTick` function from props which is the one that is linked with redux store as you have added it to mapDispatchToProps.

If you do not destructure it from props, the ccomponent will use the imported function which isn't an action created unless its passed to `dispatch` function

```
const Total = ({ total, testFinished }) => {
  const { finishedCount, totalCount, isPaussed, timeLeft, timerTick } = total;
  return (
    <div className="test-total">
      <QuestionCounter
        finishedCount={finishedCount}
        totalCount={totalCount}
        testFinished={testFinished}
      />
      <FinishButton testFinished={testFinished} />
      <TimeCounter
        timeLeft={timeLeft}
        testFinished={testFinished}
        setTimer={setTimer}
        timerTick={timerTick}
      />
      <PauseButton isPaussed={isPaussed} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, man! 
It was really hard to find it for me, because I logged timerTick in TimeCounter from props,  but it was not 'Underfind'.... but it was plane function..  I should have guessed....
Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dispatch of timer tick inside timer tick component. Because child component not aware about the actions.

Please refer below link for more details:
https://itnext.io/dispatching-actions-from-child-components-bd292a51f176

Answer (score 0):

## Response

if your component is not connected to redux you won’t be able to dispatch any action.

### What do I mean?

#### Example

```js
import React from “react”;
import { connect } from “react-redux”;

class MyCom extensa React.Component {

    componentDidMount () {
          const { action } = this.props;

          action();
     }

     render () {
     .....
     }
}

const toState = state => ({....});
const toDispatch = {
   action
};

export default connect(toState, toDispatch)(MyCom);
```

### Explains

Basically `connect` from `”react-redux”` is a HOC a high order component that on javascript world: is none but a high order function. a function that return another function.

Comment: Thank you for anser. I already have solution from Shubham Khatri.
So if you talking about TimeCounter, it take timerTick from props.